# Reverse vowels in a String Python

Tags: python

Im a beginner to your world. I have seen many attempts to answer this question using fancy builtin function and have found the answer on how to do this a thousand times but NONE using two for loops method.

I would like for the code to only reverse a vowel when it finds one in a string, using the two for loop method.

I coded something that didnt seem to work and I dont quite understand why,

```
for x in newWord:
for y in vowels:
    if x == y:
        newWord[x] = newWord[7]
```

> > > print newWord

with vowels being a list of vowels, with newWord also being a list.

This code is currently not working, like most others who have tried the two for loop method.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Besides the indentation, what isn't working about your code? and why 7 in `newWord[7]`

Comment: The 8th character of a word is not necessarily a vowel. Strings are immutable, so you cannot change a string. You have to scan a string and create another string, by altering vowels and copying everything else. It is not apparent what a correct answer to your problem might be; please provide some.

Comment: Its not swapping the characters, its printing the newWord list over and over again. I used len(newWord) to decide  where to insert the character that is how I obtain newWord[7], to insert the vowel at the end of the list.

Comment: @9000 my string or "word" is actually a list of char. i. e "foobar" = ["f", "o", "o", "b", "a", "r"]

Comment: What does it mean reverse vowels?

Comment: @PaulRooney Given s = "hello", return "holle".

Comment: So `a=u, e=o, i=i, o=e, u=a`?? Do `enumerate` and `reversed` count as fancy built in functions?

Comment: What is the expected behaviour if there are three vowels (eg. married)? Or four (eg. porcelain)?

Comment: @PaulRooney yes the vowels "aeiou'. Here I am just attempting to find a vowel in a list and append it to the end of that list. However, the ultimate goal is to read a string from front and also from the back and when you find vowels you swap them at their positions.

Comment: @Windmill  Here I am just attempting to find a vowel in a list and append it to the end of that list. So if married, then mrrdaie or if porcelain,  then  prlnoeai

Comment: I expected `porcelain` to result in `pircaleon`.

Comment: @DanD.I want to insert vowels at the end of the list, "i" is a vowel so it cannot be the second char in the final word.

Answer (score 5):

Roughly the approach you want to use is to make two passes over the list of characters.  In the first pass you find the index of each vowel, building a list of work to be done (locations of vowels to be swapped).

Then you prepare your work list by matching the first and last items until you have less than two items left in the work list.  (An odd number of vowels means that the one in the middle doesn't have to be swapped with anything).

Now you simply iterate over the work list, tuples/pairs of indexes.  Swap the character at the first offset with the character at the other one for each pair.  Done.

(This is assuming you want transform the list in place.  If not then you can either just start with a copy: `new_word = word[:]` or can iterate over `enumerate(word)` and conditionally either append the character at each point (if the offset isn't in your work list) ... or append the offset character (if this index matches one of those in your list).  I the latter case you might make your work list a dictionary instead).

Here's the code to demonstrate:

```
def rev_vowels(word):
    word = list(word)
    results = word[:]
    vowel_locations = [index for index, char in enumerate(word) if char in 'aeiou']
    work = zip(vowel_locations[:int(len(vowel_locations)/2)], reversed(vowel_locations))
    for left, right in work:
        results[left], results[right] = word[right], word[left]
    return results
```

This does use a list comprehension, the *zip()* and *reversed()* builtins, a complex slice for the first argument to *zip()*, and the Python tuple packing idiom for swapping variables.  So you might have to replace those with more verbose constructs to fulfill your "no fancy builtins" constraint.

Fundamentally, however, a list comprehension is just syntactic sugar around a *for* loop.  So, overall, this demonstrates the approach using two *for* loops over the data.  While I'm returning a copy of the data as my **results** the code would work without that.  (That's why I'm using the tuple packing idiom on line seven (just before the *return* statement).

If this question is being asked in an interview context I'm reasonably confident that this would be a reasonably good answer.  You can easily break down how to implement zip, how to expand a list comprehension into a traditional *for* suite (block), and the swap line could be two separate assignments when returning a copy rather than performing an in-place transformation on the data.

These variable names are very verbose.  But that's to make the intentions especially clear.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, Ill give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

This code should solve your problem without using any "fancy builtin functions".

```
def f(word):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    string = list(word)
    i = 0
    j = len(word)-1

    while i < j:
        if string[i].lower() not in vowels:
            i += 1
        elif string[j].lower() not in vowels:
            j -= 1
        else:
            string[i], string[j] = string[j], string[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    return "".join(string)
```

Comment: Hi Vinicius, yes, I found this code and while it achieves the ultimate goal. I did not settle with it because I would like to first  append vowels at the end of the list using two comparison for loops.

Comment: but using two nested for loops will result in time limit excedded error . i tried that method out in leetcode